# How can I get my employees more engaged in their tasks?

Tags: productivity, deadlines

I feel that not all employees are fully committed to their tasks.

I would like to see them ask more questions, make sure their work is done to the best of their ability, make sure deadlines are met, and generally see them more involved during the work day.

How can I encourage my employees to be more engaged in the average workday?

Comment: If the workers were stakeholders then the productivity would ramp up .Maybe some share scheme would work .

Answer (score 4):

Not a huge amount of detail here, but to address your points:

> I feel that not all workers are fully committed to their tasks.

"Workers" huh? Why not just call them proles. There is a job to be done and you're all in it together. Everyone at all levels needs to do their job well - including you.

> I would like to see them ask more questions

About what? If they have all the information to do their job then a lack of questions is a good thing right?

> make sure their work is done on the best side

If you feel they could do their job better, then train it out or get more able colleagues to do so.

> make sure deadlines are met

No point letting someone know when a deadline has elapsed. Make sure these are made clear well in advance and offer support.

> generally see them more involved.

If I believed my boss thought I was doing a bad job, this is the last thing I'd want. Teamwork doesn't just happen, it needs to be developed and nurtured. Yes, this means tough decisions and making sure deadlines are met but it also involves developing your staff, making them feel empowered and providing encouragement to get the job done.

It sounds like you're looking for a bigger stick, but the carrot is just as important.

Comment: in all seriousness, what's the issue with calling them 'workers?'  they are working.

Comment: It has been edited now, but the tone of the original question was that the fault was all on one side. I felt if the OP could culture more of a teamwork vibe, they'd get a lot further.